# cURL working in postman, not in Terminal (for basecamp)

Tags: php, curl, postman, basecamp

I am trying to refresh access_tokens through basecamp api. But I am facing a strange error.

The cURL request is working fine on POSTMAN (tab: form-data). But I tried every configuration of cURL in PHP, but not able to make it work.

This is the code that I am using:

```
$refresh_token = func_to_get_refresh_token();

$data='redirect_uri=xxxxmyredirecturixxxx&client_id=xxxxmyclientidxxx&client_secret=xxxxmyclientsecretxxxxx&refresh_token='.$refresh_token.'&type=refresh';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://launchpad.37signals.com/authorization/token');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$resp = curl_exec($ch);
```

I am getting back the following result from Basecamp server :

```
* upload completely sent off: 448 out of 448 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
* Server nginx is not blacklisted
< Server: nginx
< Date: Mon, 09 Feb 2015 08:05:51 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive 
< Status: 400 Bad Request
< X-Request-Id: aaec3a6c61eb5e603672a7a2e004ea7a
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Set-Cookie: _launchpad_session=BAh7BiIPc2Vzc2lvbl9pZCIlOTEwZTEyOTY0N2M1ZDMxNjM4YjJlZTI2MmRjODE0MTI%3D--7ba9863975db8a7d2c97425300abab8d5405c17a; path=/; HttpOnly; secure
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< X-Runtime: 0.011202
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
< X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
< 
* Connection #0 to host launchpad.37signals.com left intact
{"error":"authorization_expired"}
```

I have already tried almost every configuration of cURL possible from what I can find on stackoverflow.

Your Help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following small change did the trick:

```
$refresh_token = rtrim($refresh_token);
```

As it turned out, I had to remove the extra invisible character (End Of String character, in this case) before sending it to basecamp.

Answer (score 1):

Construct your `$data` as an array like:

```
$data = array(
    'redirect_uri' => 'xxxxmyredirecturixxxx',
    'client_id' => 'xxxxmyclientidxxx',
    'client_secret' => 'xxxxmyclientsecretxxxxx',
    'refresh_token' => 'xxxrefreshtokenofmyaccountxxx',
    'type' => 'refresh'
);
```

and pass that to:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

This will ensure that your values are properly URL-encoded and that the `Content-Type` header is set to `multipart/form-data` which is apparently what works with POSTman.

I suspect that the issue is really with the URL-encoding of the `redirect_uri` so if Basecamp happens to require a `Content-Type` of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` rather than `multipart/form-data` you can use the same `$data` array construction as above, but then use:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query ($data));
```

to set the content type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. This will still properly URL-encode the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing exactly the same error message and neither of the answers here helped me. As it turns out, Basecamp uses *very* long refresh tokens and the database column that I was using to store them was only set to VARCHAR(255) and this was truncating the refresh token. Increasing the size of the column resolved the issue.

Comment: I just tried to test my app with a larger field size as you suggested. Interestingly, my field is "text" type, so there is no scope to this kind of bug. For me, just trimming refresh token is working.